# Efficient way to relabel values in Pandas DataFrame column based on shared value in adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | r_id | c_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | 1 |
| 1 | y | 1 |
| 2 | z | 2 |
| 3 | u | 3 |
| 4 | v | 3 |
| 5 | w | 4 |
| 6 | x | 4 |

which you can reproduce like this:

```
import pandas as pd

r1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
r2 = ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4']
df = pd.DataFrame([r1,r2]).T
df.columns = ['r_id', 'c_id']
```

Where a row has a duplicate `r_id`, I want to relabel all cases of that `c_id` with the first `c_id` value that was given for the duplicate `r_id`.

(**Edit**: maybe this is somewhat subtle, but I therefore want to relabel `'w'`s `c_id` as `'1'`, *as well as* that belonging to the second case of `'x'`. The duplication of `'x'` shows me that *all* instances where `c_id == '1'` *and* `c_id == '2'` should have the same label.)

For a small dataframe, this works:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'r_id', 'c_id')
subgraphs = [g.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(g)]
translator = {n: sorted(list(g.nodes))[0] for g in subgraphs for n in g.nodes if n in df.c_id.values}
df['simplified'] = df.c_id.apply(lambda x: translator[x])
```

so that I get this:

|  | r_id | c_id | simplified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | y | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | z | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | u | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | v | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | w | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | x | 4 | 1 |

---

But I'm trying to do this for a table with 2.5 million rows and my computer is struggling... There must be a more efficient way to do something like this.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear and please don't change your question entirely after the answers come in.

Comment: The edit history clearly shows that 'changing the question entirely' is an absurd complaint. @Vishnudev I'm sorry you didn't understand my problem. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: By entirely I mean the logic required. Nowhere other than the code it is mentioned that network/graph is to be used. @Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I optimize my initial answer by just using the memory `id()` as a unique label for a connected set (or rather, a subgraph, since I'm using networkx to find these), and don't check any condition while I'm generating the dictionary but just use a `.get()` so that it passes gracefully past values that have no key, then this seems to work:

```
def simplify(original_df):
    df = original_df.copy()
    g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'r_id', 'c_id')
    subgraphs = [g.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(g)]
    translator = {n: id(g) for g in subgraphs for n in g.nodes}
    df['simplified'] = df.c_id.apply(lambda x: translator.get(x,x))
    return df
```

Manages to do what I want for 2,840,759 rows in 14.49 seconds on my laptop, which will do fine.